# jquery form validation for dynamic radio groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, radiobuttonlist

Essentially, I need to validate a form that is generated dynamically (unlimited number) and consists of pairs of radio groups. I've made a good progress on it, but I am stuck now. The use case: if the user selects the first radio in a pair, a hidden droplist will appear. The user must choose one of the options from that droplist (but not first option as it is a placeholder text) to make that pair valid. Now, my script is accepting the "please select" as a valid option whereas it should not.

I have a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dhLx7hnc/

Here's my jquery:

```
$(".select-suboption, .see-address").hide();

$('.show').bind('change',function(){

    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
        $(this).siblings('.select-suboption').show();
        $(this).siblings('.see-address').hide();
    } else if ($(this).val() == 2) {
        $(this).siblings('.see-address').show();
        $(this).siblings('.select-suboption').hide();
    } 
});

$(function () {
    $('#validate').click(function () {

        //Make groups
        var names = []
        $('input:radio').each(function () {
            var rname = $(this).attr('name');
            if ($.inArray(rname, names) == -1) names.push(rname);
        });

        $.each(names, function (i, name) {
            if ($('input[name="' + name + '"]:checked').length == 0) {
                alert('Please check ' + name);
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $('#validate').click(function () {

        //Make groups
        var names = $('input:radio[value="1"]').map(function () {
            return this.name;
        }).get();

        $.each(names, function (i, name) {
            var $checked = $('input[name="' + name + '"]:checked');
            if ($checked.length == 0) {
                console.log('Please check ' + name);
            } else if ($checked.val() == 1 && $checked.nextAll('.select-suboption').find('select').val() == 0) {
                console.log('Please select suboption for ' + name);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/o31Lep0b/)

Comment: Finally I've implemented this in my project but I'm facing a problem: when I click the validate button, it prompts me the errors but it's not returning false, so the form is being submitted with errors. How can this issue be fixed? Regards!

Comment: Thanks again Arun. Worked great.